Looking to translate "je ne dois plaire qu'à moi-même" into latin in four words
I am working on a piece of jewellery I would like to engrave with a motto that is important to me and others.
Being french, the message I'd like to convey is "je ne dois plaire qu'à moi-même", so basically: I am the only one whose approval I should meet.
The available space on the piece of jewellery being limited, I'm trying for a formulation in four words.
I have tried a number of options, but translation back into french sometimes results in a more-than-steamy "je dois me faire plaisir toute seule" which... well, it's a whole other sentiment, really.
My tries so far:

mihi solae placere debo
mihi solae placere habeo
nemini praeter mihi placebo
nemini alter placere debo
mihi solae placenda sum

I'd be really greatful for your help (and will show you the resulting piece when it's finished!).

The structure explored in this old question might be of use.

Note that the dative singular of solus is soli, regardless of the gender

Is "placere" the right verb? I am trying to translate "plaire", as in "gain the approval of", and steer clear of "give pleasure to".

Would a different phrase but with the same meaning work for you?

It absolutely would, yes!
